# Ehcache data persistent based on timeToIdleSeconds and timeToLive?

Tags: ehcache

I am aware about the difference between timeToIdleSeconds and timeToLiveSeconds. But if my cache also persist data on disk will these parameters remove data from disk after expiration as well or theses parameters removes data from memory only.

If i want to configure these parameters to remove data from disk after expiration how can i configure it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TTI` and `TTL` are applied to all storage tiers of Ehcache, which includes the disk tier.

Note that Ehcache does not use a background process for removing expired entries, so they will be removed:

- if accessed after their expiration time, then `get` will remove the mapping from the cache and not return it,
- or through eviction.

Comment: So you mean to say once i configure these parameters, it will apply for disk storage also by default. Once eviction period is done ehcache will remove from cache (i.e. memory )and disk as well right?

Comment: Yes to the first part, no to the second. Expired entries are not removed eagerly.

Comment: Expired entries not removed eagerly mean they are removed when? after idle timeout? I am bit confused here...

Comment: That's the topic of my second paragraph. I reformatted it for clarity.